# Failed to add a new subscription for my own onedrive 'Documents' folder

Tags: onedrive

I have failed to add a new subscription webhook URL for my personal one drive **Documents** folder ( not a business account). The request response details is as follows.

**URL:** `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions`

**Try 1**

```
  Request JSON:
    {
     "notificationUrl": "https://****.rest/OneDrive/newItemWebhook",
     "expirationDateTime": "2017-09-18T11:23:00.000Z",
     "resource": "/me/drive/root/Documents",
     "changeType": "updated",
     "clientState": "client-specific string"
    }
    Response JSON:
    {
      "error": {
      "code": "BadRequest",
      "message": "Unsupported segment type. ODataQuery: 
       users/****@outlook.com/drive/root/Documents",
      "innerError": {
      "request-id": "169755ee-bdf5-460e-8577-6f1e22777207",
      "date": "2017-09-18T10:46:07"
        }
      }
    }
```

**Try 2**

```
Request JSON:
        {
         "notificationUrl": "https://****.rest/OneDrive/newItemWebhook",
         "expirationDateTime": "2017-09-18T11:23:00.000Z",
         "resource": "/me/drive/root:/Documents",
         "changeType": "updated",
         "clientState": "client-specific string"
        }
Response JSON:
        {
          "error": {
          "code": "InvalidRequest",
          "message": "resource '/me/drive/root:/Documents' is not supported.",
          "innerError": {
          "request-id": "403229b0-0554-46c2-82b8-ede69a4ef9a2",
          "date": "2017-09-18T10:50:36"
              }
           }
         }
```

In both cases the cases the failed to add subscription webhook URL but the reason in unknown to me, means what is :

1. > Unsupported segment type. ODataQuery
2. > resource '/me/drive/root:/Documents' is not supported.

and then if I want to set webhook URL for the above mention "resource" then what will be the path for my case!

Comment: Can you update your question to include the URLs against which the JSON bodies was POSTed?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you cannot subscribe to changes in the particular folder, but to a drive, so you should subscribe to `/me/drive/root`. Then you could use driveitem delta api to track changes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_delta or use your own method (i.e. list files in the Documents folder)

Here is a bit outdated video explaining the process: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/P566